# No solution system of three equations, but bogus answers when eliminating y or z first.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$x-2y+2z=1$

$-2x+y-z=2$

$x-y+z=5$

I know the answer is no solution. If you eliminate x, you get the standard 0 equals a number. However, if you eliminate y or z as the first 2 steps, you get x equals different values. Why?

Comment: How is this “bogus?” Either way, you’ve shown that the system is inconsistent.

Comment: Why can’t you select any letter to eliminate as step 1? I know the answer, but trying to explain why this is the case.

Comment: What makes you think that you can’t?

Comment: Remember, these three equations, as well as all of their consequences, must all hold, all at the same time. If you find that $x$ comes to two different numbers, that's an inconsistency, since $x$ would have to equal two different numbers at the same time. Remember, you should always check your possible solutions to ensure that they are actual solutions! (Though, the full method of Gaussian elimination, when done properly to completion, never throws up false solutions.)

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking matrices would be a better way anyways.  I’ve just never had one where x=two different values.

Comment: By "x equals different values" I guess you mean you get two different equations say $x=a$ and $x=b$. Then you can subtract them and get $0=a-b$, which is the "0 equals a [nonzero] number" inconsistency that you're used to.

Comment: Helpful to keep in mind that what you're really doing when solving an inconsistent system of linear equation is a proof by contradiction. You suppose all these equations hold at once, and then prove False, whence you conclude that at least one of the equations must not hold.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are getting more than one value for a variable means that the system is inconsistent and there is no defined solution.

In 3D, these equations define planes. In this case, the planes would not be intersecting at a fixed point. Instead they would be giving two or three lines. The 'bogus' values you get would be points on these lines.